# Invalid route action: [ProductController]

Tags: laravel

I have my view as follow resources/views/shop/index.blade.php

I have a controller named ProductController.
In the route, I have the following

```
Route::get('/',  [
    'uses' => 'ProductConroller',
    'as' => 'product.index'
]);
```

There is an error;
**ProductController` is not invokable.
The controller class ProductController is not invokable. Did you forget to add the __invoke method or is the controller's method missing in your routes file?**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ProductController extends Controller
{
    //

    public function getIndex()
    {
        return view('shop.index');
    }
}
```

Please, I don't know what to do else. I have tried everything. Laravel 8 [image]

Comment: The correct code is for laravel 8 `Route::get('/shop, [ProductController::class, 'getIndex']);` you misspelled on call the function name `index` should be `getIndex`

Comment: you either need to tell the router what method on the controller to use for the action as sta has said, or you need to make it a single action controller with an `__invoke` method

Comment: @sta not working the way. I just tried now.

Comment: Now showing error 404, page not found

Comment: @lagbox I have tried to do that severally __invoke() but not found, show error 404

Comment: a 404 is a different error

Answer (score -1):

I finally got it by using

```php
use App\Http\Controllers\ProductController;

Route::get('/', [ProductController::class, 'getIndex']);
```

It is funny though, it took me several hours to figure what is needed to be done.

Comment: Its new update in Laravel 8.0, Your older code is valid in older versions of Laravel.

Comment: Yeah, I used to do that but Laravel 8.0 is totally new for me. I need to retake my Laravel and learn as a beginner.